# Extracting tuples from a list in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, tuples, iteration

I have a dataframe with 12 column. I would like to extract the rows of a column depending on the values of another column.

Sample of my dataframe

```
order_id    order_type   order_items
45           Lunch       [('Burger', 5), ('Fries', 6)]
12           Dinner      [('Shrimp', 10), ('Fish&Chips', 7)]
44           Lunch       [('Salad', 9), ('Steak', 9)]
23           Breakfast   [('Coffee', 2), ('Eggs', 3)]
```

I would like to extract the breakfast, lunch and dinner menu by extracting the first item of each `tuple`.
and extract the number of orders from the next item in the tuple.

Each item is type string according to this line of code

```
print(type(df['order_items'][0]))
>> <class 'str'>
```

I tried to apply a filter to extract the breakfast menu:

```
BreakfastLst=df.loc[df['order_type'] == 'Breakfast']['order_items']
```

but the output looks like this, and I can't use a `for loop` to iterate through sublists and access the tuples.

```
2                           [('Coffee', 4), ('Eggs', 7)]
7                           [('Coffee', 2), ('Eggs', 3)]
8      [('Cereal', 7), ('Pancake', 8), ('Coffee', 4),...
9      [('Cereal', 3), ('Eggs', 1), ('Coffee', 1), ('...
```

I also tried to convert to `lists`:

```
orderTypeLst = df(['order_type'])['order_items'].apply(list)
```

and then extract the lists by doing this:

```
breakFast=orderTypeLst['Breakfast']
lunch=orderTypeLst['Lunch']
dinner=orderTypeLst['Dinner']
```

but the output is a string. And I can't iterate through that either.

```
["[('Coffee', 4), ('Eggs', 7)]",
 "[('Coffee', 2), ('Eggs', 3)]",
 "[('Cereal', 7), ('Pancake', 8), ('Coffee', 4), ('Eggs', 8)]"]
```

As for `dictionaries` I tried the below, but the output is duplicated:

```
pd.Series(outlierFile.order_type.values,index=outlierFile.order_items).to_dict()
```

output sample

```
 "[('Fries', 1), ('Steak', 6), ('Salad', 8), ('Chicken', 10)]": 'Lunch',
 "[('Cereal', 6), ('Pancake', 8), ('Eggs', 3)]": 'Breakfast',
 "[('Shrimp', 9), ('Salmon', 9)]": 'Dinner',
 "[('Pancake', 3), ('Coffee', 5)]": 'Breakfast',
 "[('Eggs', 1), ('Pancake', 1), ('Coffee', 5), ('Cereal', 5)]": 'Breakfast'
```

my desired output is a clean version of each order_type (list or dictionary) so I can iterate through the tuples and extract the needed items.

Any input would be helpful
Thanks,

Comment: Are `df['order_items']` strings?

Comment: each item is a a list of tuples. sample output: 
`[('Shrimp', 10), ('Fish&Chips', 7)]` . The type is string.

Comment: based on your edit, it is indeed a str i suppose?

Comment: yes I just checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` after evaluation:

```
my_dict = df.groupby('order_type')['order_items'].apply(lambda x: sum(x, [])).to_dict()
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Breakfast': [('Coffee', 2), ('Eggs', 3)],
 'Dinner': [('Shrimp', 10), ('Fish&Chips', 7)],
 'Lunch': [('Burger', 5), ('Fries', 6), ('Salad', 9), ('Steak', 9)]}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. But this returns `ValueError: malformed node or string:  [('Shrimp', 10), ('Fish&Chips', 7)]`

Comment: Is it from the apply line?

Comment: I think it is caused by the first apply in the first line

Comment: It seems like there is an invalid python object, whereas the element in your comment looks fine.

Comment: I have around 500 rows and they all look pretty similar to me. What do you think the invalid object might be?

Comment: I don't know why, but I was able to get the dictionary by only running the second line. `my_dict = df.groupby('order_type')['order_items'].apply(lambda x: sum(x, [])).to_dict()`


Thank you

Comment: would you mind editing your answer so I can choose it as the correct one. Thank you.