# Finding unknown values in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataset with 500 restaurant orders, and their totals. I want to identify the outliers in the dataset. And then decide if they are valid data points or wrong values. And then remove the invalid ones.

The problem is I only have the total price of the orders, the item name, and the quantity ordered.
I was wondering if it is possible to get the price of each item.

Each item in the dictionary presents one order. The Key is the total price, and the value is a list of tuples, each tuple present the item name and the quantity ordered.

Sample of my dataset in a dictionary format(I have it as two columns in a dataframe too):

```
{1215.5: [('Shrimp', 10), ('Fish&Chips', 6), ('Salmon', 8), ('Pasta', 5)],
 1230.0: [('Shrimp', 10), ('Salmon', 10), ('Fish&Chips', 8)],
 1234.0: [('Salmon', 9), ('Fish&Chips', 3), ('Pasta', 8), ('Shrimp', 10)],
 1292.5: [('Pasta', 7), ('Salmon', 9), ('Fish&Chips', 7), ('Shrimp', 9)],
 1301.5: [('Pasta', 5), ('Shrimp', 9), ('Salmon', 8), ('Fish&Chips', 10)],
 1314.5: [('Shrimp', 10), ('Pasta', 5), ('Fish&Chips', 10), ('Salmon', 7)],
 1343.5: [('Shrimp', 8), ('Fish&Chips', 10), ('Salmon', 9), ('Pasta', 7)]}
```

My desired output is to obtain the price of each item. By doing this I hope I can be able to decide if the total is a valid data point or an outlier.

I tried taking the third line and store the value in a list
`A`

```
[('Salmon', 9), ('Fish&Chips', 3), ('Pasta', 8), ('Shrimp', 10)]
```

And the total price of these items `B`

```
[1234.0]
```

Then I tried converting my first list to an array

```
    A=np.array(lst)
```

The output

```
array([['Salmon', '9'],
       ['Fish&Chips', '3'],
       ['Pasta', '8'],
       ['Shrimp', '10']], dtype='<U10')
```

The shapes

```
A.shape
(4,2)
B.shape
(1,)
```

Then applied the function

```
X, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
```

but the output returns an error message

```
LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions
```

I know that m has to be equal for the function to work. But I am not sure how to change the shape of `A`.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: You should construct an [overdetermined] system of linear equations and solve it. For example, the first list becomes `1215.5=10*Shrimp+6*Fish+8*Salmon+5*Pasta`.

Comment: As a side note, your format is very unsafe because it does not allow to store more than one order with the same price. You should have converted the dictionary to a list.

Comment: If the dataset can have wrong values, system of linear equations might not be able to get a correct answer.

Comment: @SacrificerXY True, if the system is overdetermined, the only hope is to get the least square approximation.

Comment: @DYZ I though of that but I don't know if I should use `NumPy.linalg.solve` because I don't have experience with that kind of functions.

Comment: I have few errors in the orders. But I think they are fixable if I can determine the price per item.

Comment: For example: I have one order with `(salmon,10),(salmon,7)` If I knew the price of 1 salmon I can determine if the order was for 17 salmons. Or this datapoint is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use construct a [possibly overdetermined] system of linear equations and solve it. For example, the first list becomes `1215.5=10*Shrimp+6*Fish+8*Salmon+5*Pasta`.

Assuming that the name of your dictionary is `d`, the matrix `A` of the system is given by:

```
A = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d[x]).set_index(0) for x in d], axis=1)\
                 .fillna(0).T
```

(And I strongly suggest that you do not use `dict` as the storage container.) The vector `B` is the list of keys:

```
B = list(d.keys())
```

The answer is:

```
X, _, _, _ = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
#array([35. , 27.5, 41. , 54. ])
```

You only need the first part of the returned tuple.

Comment: i think it's take long time for every output ?

Comment: @soheshdoshi 500 orders is 500 equations. It is a very small system. Why would solving it take a long time?

Comment: @DYZ thank you, I got this error. I think it might be related to the dictionary? `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (14, 459), indices imply (13, 459)`

Comment: In which statement do you get it?

Comment: the first line A value

Comment: this the post where I was trying to convert my values to lists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151118/extracting-tuples-from-a-list-in-pandas-dataframe/58151226?noredirect=1#comment102686652_58151226

Comment: If I can use lists. How would I convert my list of tuples to a matrix? I tried `np.array` but it is not returning the correct output. I updated my post.